# updating from mysqli to pdo - code updates

Tags: php, mysql

I instantiated a PDO object instead of a mysqli object in my database class.  Obviously my mysqli functions no longer work.  How do I update this line.

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_row(database::query($query));
```

one_db::$db holds the pdo resource...query is just...

```
public function query($query) 
{
    return one_db::$db->query($query);
}
```

Actually I'm not sure if this needs updating as well to work with PDO...

Here is my PDO instantiation, I left in the mysqli for comparison

```
private function __construct() 
{
    self::create_pdo_object();
}

private function create_pdo_object()
{
    try {
        self::$db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

private function create_mysqli_object()
{
    self::$db=new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);   
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `create_pdo_object()` method and a constructor that just calls said method? Wouldn't be easier to get rid of `create_pdo_object()` and put all that code in the constructor anyway?

Comment: Yeah, NullUserException has the right idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might ought to consider using the factory pattern. Unfortunately, in your case, I don't want to rewrite your entire class so we're gonna use a modified factory pattern.  Create a function named factory() like so:

```
public static function factory($type = 'mysqli')
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'pdo':
            return self::create_pdo_object();
        case 'mysqli':
        default:
            return self::create_mysqli_object();
    }
}
```

Incidentally, if you're going to use `self` then your functions should be declared `static`. In which case, it's considered best practice to [prefix them with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140222/how-to-use-this-in-zend-framework-views/8141257#8141257).  And if you're gonna go *that* route, then you might as well follow the convention for [camel casing function names](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.funcdef.php). (although, it could be argued that those functions should be public in case you don't *want* to use factory, in which case you should omit the underscore prefix).

Also, your `__construct()` function should have the `public` access modifier. You could call `factory()` from within your constructor, but they are static methods using a static class member (`self::$db`), so instantiating an object is kind of pointless. Nevertheless, here is the code:

```
public function __construct($type = 'mysqli') 
{
    self::factory($type);
}

public static function factory($type = 'mysqli')
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'pdo':
            // return self::createPdoObject();
            // or, if private  
            return self::_createPdoObject();
        case 'mysqli':
        default:
            // return self::createMysqliObject();
            // or, if private  
            return self::_createMysqliObject();
    }
}

// public static function createPdoObject()
// or
private static function _createPdoObject()
{
    try {
        self::$db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// public static function createMysqliObject()
// or
private static function _createMysqliObject()
{
    self::$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);   
}
```

As far as fetching a row with PDO, you would need to alter the code to something like:

```
if ($db instanceof PDO) {
    $query = $db->prepare($sqlSelectString);
    $query->execute();

    // or use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC if you want arrays instead
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

If this code exists in your db class, then you would change `$db` to `self::$db`, but I'm not sure where you would want to put that code..

For more information on querying using PDO, check out [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: _ is used for private and protected accoring to Zend coding standard